# how to insert any value to registry using C#?

Tags: c#, registry

I have to insert this to the registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\AutoStartOnConnect]
"AutoRun"="d:\\MyFolder\\MyProgram.exe"
```

How would I do this in C#?

Comment: Are you sure that your program will have sufficient permissions to access the Registry, particularly `HKLM`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
string name = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\AutoStartOnConnect";
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(name, true))
{
    if (key == null)
    {
        // Whatever you want to do if the key isn't found
    }
    else
    {
        key.SetValue("AutoRun", @"d:\MyFolder\MyProgram.exe");
    }
}
```

If you use [`CreateSubKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ad51f2dx.aspx) instead of `OpenSubKey`, that will create it if it doesn't already exist (or open it for write otherwise) - but I suspect that in most cases, if the key doesn't exist then that indicates the rest of the system isn't in an appropriate state for your app.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) class:

```
var path = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\AutoStartOnConnect";
using (var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path, true))
{
    if (key != null)
    {
        key.SetValue("AutoRun", @"d:\MyFolder\MyProgram.exe");
    }
}
```